# How to change label text according to the comboBox value selected?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, label

I am trying to associate a label with the ComboBox selected value but That label is not getting triggered.What is wrong with my code?

```
    private void comboBoxCrewMember_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string crewMemberName=comboBoxCrewMember.Text;//ComboBox
        string rankName=crewMemberManager.GetRankName(crewMemberName);
        lblRankValue.Text = rankName;//label
    }
```

My ComboBox consists of name of crew memebers which are selected and the label consists of rank of that particular crew member which is fetched by the method GetRankName.

On execution,I get the whole list of crew members'names but on selecting those names nothing happens to the label.

Comment: Did you bind the combobox' onindexchanged event ?

Comment: place breakpoint,and look if event is getting fired or not.

Comment: are you sure that your GetRankName() function works properly?

Comment: 1.pleae share your GetRankName() function code. 2.use comboBoxCrewMember.SelectedValue.ToString() instead of comboBoxCrewMember.Text.

Answer (score 1):

its quite simple bro..

```
private void comboBoxCrewMember_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string crewMemberName=comboBoxCrewMember.SelectedValue.ToString();
    lblRankValue.Text = crewMemberManager.GetRankName(crewMemberName);

}
```

what u need to make sure ix that GetRankName() is returning only one value.. and thats it..
hope it helps
you can minimize thix code even..

like this

```
private void comboBoxCrewMember_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblRankValue.Text = crewMemberManager.GetRankName(comboBoxCrewMember.SelectedValue.ToString(););
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure your Event is bound
2. Make sure your  `crewMemberManager.GetRankName(crewMemberName);` method works fine
3. Make sure your ComboBox text is the value you want to parse to the `crewMemberManager.GetRankName(crewMemberName);` method

IF I were use , I would you something like below to retrieve the SelectedValue of combobox

```
comboBox1.SelectedIndex;selectedItem.ToString()
Object selectedItem = comboBox1.SelectedItem;
crewMemberManager.GetRankName(selectedItem.ToString());
```

And also I don' think your problem is with ComboBox or comboBox's selection, I think that your `crewMemberManager.GetRankName(crewMemberName);` method is caussing this issue , Please make sure that your crewMemberManager.GetRankName(crewMemberName); method works fine,

Answer (score 0):

```
string crewMemberName=comboBoxCrewMember.Text;//ComboBox
```

the above will give you a string "crewMemberName", now make sure that the bellow method

```
crewMemberManager.GetRankName(crewMemberName)
```

is return type of string and it is written like bellow in the file

```
public string crewMemberManager.GetRankName(string name)
```

if not do same otherwise please provide that method for further verification.